# Compiler error "error: stray '\' in program" in macro definition

Tags: python, c++, macros, scons

While trying to compile [this program](https://github.com/s5z/zsim) with [SCons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCons), we faced this error:

```
build/opt/zsim_harness.cpp:315:5: error: stray '\' in program
build/opt/zsim_harness.cpp:315:5: error: stray '#' in program
build/opt/zsim_harness.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
build/opt/zsim_harness.cpp:310:24: error: 'ZSIM_BUILDVERSION' was not declared in this  scope
build/opt/zsim_harness.cpp:315:5: error: expected ')' before 'n'
build/opt/zsim_harness.cpp:315:5: error: 'ZSIM_BUILDVERSION' was not declared in this scope
```

The line that has this error is:

```
info("Starting zsim, built %s (rev %s)", ZSIM_BUILDDATE, ZSIM_BUILDVERSION);
```

`ZSIM_BUILDVERSION` is a macro which is defined in SConstruct

```
if os.path.exists(".git"):
    env.Command(versionFile, allSrcs + [".git/index", "SConstruct"],
        'echo "#define ZSIM_BUILDDATE \\""`date`\\""\\\\n#define ZSIM_BUILDVERSION \\""`python misc/gitver.py`\\""" >>' + versionFile)
else:
    env.Command(versionFile, allSrcs + ["SConstruct"],
        'echo "#define ZSIM_BUILDDATE \\""`date`\\""\\\\n#define ZSIM_BUILDVERSION \\""no git repo\\""" >>' + versionFile)
```

The SCons version is 2.1.0. How can I fix that?

It seems that SCons will generate a file, *version.h*, which looks like:

```
#define ZSIM_BUILDDATE "Sat Apr 19 11:07:38 CET 2014"\n#define ZSIM_BUILDVERSION "master:10:a8c417b:1fc 1+ 1- 6b4f4490"
```

Comment: You are not showing thw macro definition, you are showing some Python code that presumably generates one. Where is the output of that code?

Comment: How about separating the two MACROS in two lines?

Comment: Is that \n intentional?

Comment: @Dieter Lücking: I don't know.

Comment: @Steve: the '\n' should separate the two macros. Isn't that?

Comment: @mahmood. Normally... yes. But sometimes the interpreter behaves differently on different OSs and python encodings.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the Python code has too many backslashes in this line:

```
'echo "#define ZSIM_BUILDDATE \\""`date`\\""\\\\n#define ZSIM_BUILDVERSION \\""no git repo\\""" >>' + versionFile)
```

This is being parsed by one less program that the code expects, so it ends up that '\\n' ends up in the file as the two characters '\' and 'n', rather than being parsed into a single newline character. The code is trying to avoid Python inserting the newline, which would break the shell command, and instead pass the escape sequence to the shell for *it* to change to a newline. Python provides an easier way to do this in the form of raw strings:

```
r'echo "#define ZSIM_BUILDDATE \""`date`\""\\n#define ZSIM_BUILDVERSION \""no git repo\""" >>' + versionFile)
```

and when it's put like this, you can see the error more clearly: the shell sees the escape sequence '\', so it prints a single \, followed by an n, rather than the escape sequence '\n' which would cause it to put a newline in the file.

Comment: @Ivc: we still have the problem. I thought it has been gone!. This time I see `error: invalid suffix "fc" on integer constant`. It is related to the generated version

Comment: The question has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168086/n-is-treated-as-and-n