# '\n' is treated as '\' and 'n'

Tags: python, shell

The following python code

```
env.Command(versionFile, allSrcs + [".git/index", "SConstruct"],
        'echo "#define ZSIM_BUILDDATE \\""`date`\\""\\\\n#define ZSIM_BUILDVERSION \\""`python misc/gitver.py`\\""" >>' + versionFile)
```

produces an output like this

```
$ cat build/opt/version.h
#define ZSIM_BUILDDATE "Sat Apr 19 13:31:41 CET 2014"\n#define ZSIM_BUILDVERSION "master:10:a8c417b:2fc 3+ 2- d5cec7e7"
```

As you can see it doesn't understand that `'\n'` means `new line+carriage return`. Instead it just print `'\'` and `'n'`.

How can I fix that?

P.S: This question is a follow-up for this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23166975/error-stray-in-program-in-macro-definition). the previous post was general and didn't pinpoint to the problem. Also I use scons for build. any help would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: What should be the outcome ... just to ensure we understand your \\"" and \\\\n right.

Comment: Looks like the preceding \ is \\ in your case!

Comment: You mean reducing `\\\\n` to `\\n`?

Comment: Didn't you just [ask about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23166975/error-stray-in-program-in-macro-definition)? The problem is still the same - an extra level of escaping. Change `\\\\n` to `\\n` as described there.

Comment: @mahmood Yes, if I count them in your sample you have 2 \\ (escaped backslash) and 1 n

Comment: @Mike Seymour: yes but there is no difference between `\\\\n` and `\\n`

Comment: @MikeSeymour Shouldn't that be `\\\n`?

Comment: @mahmood: Yes there is. There's an extra level of escaping in the first, so that it reduces to the two characters \ and `n`, rather than a single newline character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `echo -e ...` so that `echo` understands that `\n` is an escape sequence for newline

Answer (score 5):

That's not actually either a python or a C++ question as you are complaining about the behavior of shell quoting (some shells allow escape codes like \n in arguments when you use something like `echo -e` though).

So if you want to get a newline in, try producing it in Python already (newline inside of quoted strings will make it into the argument of echo) rather than producing some escape sequence that the shell will not further process.

Comment: Yes the trick is to use `\\n` along with `echo -e`. Thanks

Comment: Actually, I'd refrain from using `echo -e` here since you have various other variables pasted into that command line and you most likely do not want any `\\` that might be inside of them interpreted as an escape sequence either.  I repeat: try producing the newline in Python already.

Answer (score 1):

```
'\\\\n' == '\\' + '\\' + 'n'
```

You're escaping 2 backslashes, so in the next interpretation it comes down to `\\n`.
So just replace `\\\\n` with `\\n`